# Install Linux on RAID system or outside in separate partition?

Tags: raid, root-filesystem

I have a Linux box with 4 HDDs which I will configure as RAID5. Should I install Linux rootfs on a partition ontop of the RAID or should I first build a partition on one of the bare disks and then build the RAID with a partition behind the rootfs partition?

What is recommended? I guess if I have the rootfs on the RAID it will also survive a HDD crash. If the rootfs is outside the RAID and this disk crashes, everything is gone. Correct?

Comment: I'd recommend LVM on top of software RAID. That's what I have, and it works well for me. LVM and sw RAID go together like peanut butter and jelly.

Comment: Why not to get benefits of storing rootfs on RAID? Even should you have  problems to boot due to any reason you always may try to recover with any bootable LiveCD of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you did not mention if you have a hardware RAID, or if you will be doing it in software via something like mdadm.
my recommendation is stay away from software raid, which gets implemented during and after your system boots because it relies on the linux operating system to first be booted and running.  Any power outages can cause file system corruption negating the purpose of the software raid.

That, along with a hardware raid setup, does not protect you from file system corruption or if system files get misconfigured causing the system to either not boot or not run.  in my opinion this is the most common problem, and not a failed hard drive.

with a hardware raid, i think the choice comes down to do you need your system always running 24/7?  if so then hardware raid can protect against 1 or more failed disk drives, that is its main purpose.  If not then it might be little value added, and you would be better served by using 1 of those 4 drives as a mirror copy (not raid-1) containing a complete backup of your operating system hard drive such that you can boot either disk drive.  Understand that what i am saying is different than two drives as hardware raid-1, because if you mess up your files on a raid-1 setup then both drives are messed up.  My way is you only update your backup operating system drive from the working drive that you know is good and configured properly.
And as a suggestion since you have 4 drives total, and if you share my opinion that modern hard disk drives have a low failure rate:

1. drive 1 = production operating system always running
2. drive 2 = offline copy of drive 1, only updated to mirror drive 1 when you know drive 1 is 100% functional
3. drive 3 = all other data not pertaining to operating system
4. drive 4 = backup copy of drive 3.

if drive 1 or 3 fails to spin up, then you have drive 2 and 4 to fall back on and manage the problem.

if operating system drive 1 fails to boot or gets messed up, but drive still works, then you just reinstall linux operating system on it; your data is all on drive 3 and that is backed up to drive 4.
you can also boot on backup drive 2, mount and fix drive 1 by finding out what's different on it versus the working drive2.

Comment: I will probably use a fifth drive for linux and use the others as RAID. Thanks.